# Getting triple-tap for Gyration Media Center remote working in Windows shell

Tags: windows, shell, windows-media-center, remote-control

I have [this Gyration remote](http://www.scan.co.uk/Products/Gyration-GYR3101EU-Media-Center-Vista-Remote-Control) which, out of the box, does not support triple-tap for text entry outside of Media Center; only numbers can be entered in the Windows shell.  Gyration have a [patch](http://www.gyration.com/images/stories/downloads/MEdia%20center%20remote%20TripleTap32bitWinOS.zip) that supposedly allows this, but it hasn't worked for me.

I'm not alone in this regard it seems though.  I've seem some discussion on removing and reinstalling USB devices to get this working, but nothing I'd really trust not to screw something else up.

Does anyone have any tips for getting this functionality working properly?

Answer (score 1):

This option is just not available on this product, i had the same one and had the same problem so i sold it on ebay.

Trust me i have been on every message board and support site and there is sure fire way to get this functioanlity

Comment: Many claim to have this functionality working fine though.  I can't imagine they're *all* Gyration shills :)